# Toggle Checkbox in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a checkbox in the HeaderTemplate of a TemplateField in a Gridview Control. I want to use this checkbox to toggle a telephone number from a full 10 digits to the last 4 digits and back again as needed. I have no issues with this when the checkbox is not in the Gridview.

I know the below code will not work and I have run out of ideas after a few days but cannot seem to get my brain around a way to do this other than using jQuery.

I have commented my code below and show what values I need to see. Any ideas are much appreciated.

The HeaderTemplate of the TemplateField:

```
      <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkToggle" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
        oncheckedchanged="chkTelephone_CheckedChanged" />           
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTelephone" runat="server" Text="Telephone"></asp:Label>
      </HeaderTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void chkTelephone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chkSwitch = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].FindControl("chkToggle") as CheckBox; //true / false
        Label lblTelephone = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblTelephone") as Label; //8885551234   from checkbox in TemplateHeader

        string result1 = lblTelephone.Text.Substring(lblTelephone.Text.Length - 10, 3); //888
        string result2 = lblTelephone.Text.Substring(lblTelephone.Text.Length - 7, 3); //555
        string result3 = lblTelephone.Text.Substring(lblTelephone.Text.Length - Math.Min(4, lblTelephone.Text.Length)); //1234

        if (chkSwitch.Checked)                   
        {
            //Needs to show 1234
            lblTelephone.Text = result3.ToString();
            //once this line runs the value of lblTelephone.Text is now 1234 so when I Toggle again and chkSwitch is activated
            //it now tries to peform the action on the new or current value of lblTelephone.Text which is set to 1234.  
            //This is my issue.  I need to get it from the original 10 digit string
        }
        else
        {
            //needs to show 8885551234
            lblTelephone.Text = result1.ToString() + result2.ToString() + result3.ToString();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "TEST";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@STUFF", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Stuff.Text;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MORESTUFF", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MoreStuff.Text;
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this in the end.  I created a new template field and kept the full unformatted phone number in this field.  I hid this using code behind.  I never change the lblHiddenTel field value.

Markup for the new template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CopiedPhone" SortExpression="Telephone">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Telephone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHiddenTel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Telephone") %>' Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind
First, hide the data row:

```
  e.Row.Cells[19].Visible = false;
```

Then within the checked:

```
    protected void chkTelephone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int CCnt = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1;
                CheckBox chkSwitch = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[CCnt].FindControl("chkToggle") as CheckBox; //true / false -- this has to be the number of columns.
                Label lblTelephone = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblTelephone") as Label; //8885551234 
                Label lblHiddenTel = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblHiddenTel") as Label; //8885551234 


                string formatShort = chkSho.ToString() + "-" + lblHiddenTel.Text.Substring(lblHiddenTel.Text.Length - Math.Min(4, lblHiddenTel.Text.Length));
                string formatFone = "(" + lblHiddenTel.Text.Substring(lblHiddenTel.Text.Length - 10, 3) + ") "
                        + lblHiddenTel.Text.Substring(lblHiddenTel.Text.Length - 7, 3) + "-"
                        + lblHiddenTel.Text.Substring(lblHiddenTel.Text.Length - Math.Min(4, lblHiddenTel.Text.Length));
                if (chkSwitch.Checked)
                {
                    lblTel.Text = formatShort;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblTel.Text = formatFone;
                }
            }


        }
```